# Send transaction to a smart contract deployed on injective chain using keplr failed

Tags: typescript, transactions, frontend, blockchain, smartcontracts

I have deployed a smart contract in injective testnet.
Then I tried to run query and execute transaction to it.
query tx successed.
But execute transaction is failed.

I use keplr wallet, and send tx code is like this:

```
const { txRaw } = createTransaction({
  pubKey,
  chainId,
  fee: DEFAULT_STD_FEE,
  message: msg,
  sequence: accountDetails.sequence,
  timeoutHeight: timeoutHeight.toNumber(),
  accountNumber: baseAccount.accountNumber,
})

const result = await keplr.sendTx(
  chainId,
  CosmosTxV1Beta1Tx.TxRaw.encode(txRaw).finish(),
  BroadcastMode.Sync,
)
```

Then, I received error msg.

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid mode

Answer (score 0):

Not the nicest solution but replacing `BroadcastMode.Sync,` with `"sync"` worked for me.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Do you have any documentation to support this solution please?

Comment: Thank you! I haven't found any documentation for this solution. I faced the same issue and found this question while trying to find an answer. At some point I tried "sync" and that seemed to work so I thought I would share how I got it to work.